# bitwise AND in C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have defined an enum like this:

```
enum blStatus {
   Class1 = 0x40,           /* 0000,0100,0000 */
   Class2 = 0x80,           /* 0000,1000,0000 */
   Class3 = 0x100,          /* 0001,0000,0000 */
   Class4 = 0x200           /* 0010,0000,0000 */
}
```

Now, somewhere in the code I have:

```
 if ( status &= Class1 )
   ++c1;
 else if ( status &= Class2 )
   ++c2;
 else if ( status &= Class3 )
   ++c3;
 else if ( status &= Class4 )
   ++c4;
```

Assume, the status hat this value:

```
 status = 143   /* 0000,1000,1111 */
```

While debugging, none of the conditions is true. However "status &= Class2" is:

```
 0000,1000,1111 & 0000,1000,0000 = 0000,1000,0000
```

and the c2 counter must be incremented. but while debugging, all conditions are passed (ignored) and no counter increment. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use & instead of &=.**

When you do x &= y you are getting:

```
 x = x & y;
```

What you really want in your code:

```
if ( status & Class1 )
```

Now, after each if clause, you leave the value of status untouched.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are changing the `status` in:

```
if ( status &= Class1 )
```

`status &= Class1` is same as `status = status & Class1` as a result status changes to `0`:

```
status = 0000 1000 1111
Class1 = 0000 0100 0000  &
-----------------------
status = 0000 0000 0000
```

Since you intend to just check the bits you don't need to do an assignment:

```
if ( status & Class1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

because `if ( status &= Class1 )` will assign 0 to status so in all next conditions value of status will 0 so none of the condition will be executed and non of the conter incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `&=` puts computation result into left operand (equals `a = a & b`).
After computation the expression `(status &= Class1)` the `status` variable is `0` and all following conditions are `FALSE`.